# Why does Round[2.75,0.1] return 2.800000000003?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica 8.0.1

Any one could explain what would be the logic behind this result

```
In[24]:= Round[10.75, .1]

Out[24]= 10.8

In[29]:= Round[2.75, .1]

Out[29]= 2.8000000000000003
```

I have expected the second result above to be 2.8?

EDIT 1:

I was trying to do the above for formatting purposes only to make the number fit in the space. I ended up doing the following to get the result I want:

```
In[41]:= NumberForm[2.75,2]
Out[41]   2.8
```

I wish Mathematica has printf() like formatting function. I find formatting numbers in Mathematica for exact field width and form a little awkward compared to using printf() formatting rules.

EDIT 2:
I tried $MaxExtraPrecision=1000 on some number I was trying for format/round, but it did not work, that is why I posted this question. Here it is

```
In[42]:= $MaxExtraPrecision=1000;
Round[2035.7520395261859,.1]

Out[43]= 2035.8000000000002


In[46]:= $MaxExtraPrecision=50;
Round[2.75,.1]

Out[47]= 2.8000000000000003
```

### EDIT 3:

I found this way, to format a number to one decimal point only. Use Numberform, but first need to find what n-digit precision to use by counting the number of digits to the left of the decimal point, then adding 1.

```
In[56]:= x=2035.7520395261859;
NumberForm[x,IntegerLength[Round@x]+1]

Out[57]//NumberForm= 2035.8
```

### EDIT 4:

The above (Edit 3) did not work for numbers such as

```
a=2.67301785 10^7
```

After some trials, I found Accounting Form to do what I want. AccountingForm gets rid of the 10^n form which NumberForm did not:

```
In[76]:= x=2035.7520395261859;
AccountingForm[x,IntegerLength[Round@x]+1]

Out[77]//AccountingForm= 2035.8

In[78]:= x=2.67301785 10^7;
AccountingForm[x,IntegerLength[Round@x]+1]

Out[79]//AccountingForm= 26730178.5
```

For formatting numerical values, the best language I found was Fortran, followed COBOL and also by those languages that use or support printf() standard formatting. With Mathematica, one can do such formatting I am sure, but it sure seems too complicated to me. I never understood why Mathematics does not have Printf[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Number/AccountingForm` can take a list in the second argument, the second item of which is how many digits after the decimal place to show:

```
In[61]:= x=2035.7520395261859;

In[62]:= AccountingForm[x,{Infinity,3}]

Out[62]//AccountingForm= 2035.752
```

Perhaps this is useful.

Answer (score 11):

Not all decimal (base 10) numbers with a finite number of digits are representable in binary (base 2) with a finite number of digits.  E.g. 0.1 is not representable in binary, just like 1/3 ~= 0.33333... is not representable in decimal.  Mathematica (and other software) will only use a limited number of decimal digits when showing the number to hide this effect.  However, occasionally it might happen that enough decimal digits are shown that the mismatch becomes visible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

**EDIT**

This command will show you what happens when you find the closes binary representation of 0.1 using 20 binary digits, then convert it back to decimal:

```
RealDigits[FromDigits[RealDigits[1/10, 2, 20], 2], 10]
```

Answer (score 7):

The number is stored in base 2, rather than base 10 (decimal). It's impossible to represent `2.8` in base 2, so it uses the closest value: `2.8000000000000003`

Comment: The closest value in really is just `2.8`. Consider: `a = N[FromDigits[RealDigits[2.8, 2], 2], 30]; b = 
 N[FromDigits[RealDigits[Round[2.75, .1], 2], 2], 30]; {14/5 - a, 
 b - 14/5}` gives `{1.7763568394003*10^-16, 2.6645352591004*10^-16}`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov actually, the closest value to 2.8 for MMA's machine numbers is 2.79999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 (and next closest is 2.800000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875). And exact number 2.8 (i.e. `28/10` in Wolfram) is a recurring binary fraction `2+Sum[12*16^-n,{n,1,∞}]`.